# Error importing a Django project from windows to linux

Tags: python, django

I worked in a project using python3 and django from a Windows 7 computer, now I am at home in my GNU/Linux one and I am trying to make it work but I have some errors.

I unpackage the whole thing in a folder and in that one I have installed a virtualenv with django, inside the folder I put the project I have, then I make

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
python3 manage.py runserver
```

I log in in the server and everything is there, every data, model, etc.

So far works well. but then I try to run a script  and got this error:

```
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)   File "/home/alex/proyectosP/ahq/11_env/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py",
line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import   File
"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load   File
"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line
2237, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line
2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
ImportError: No module named 'subastas'
```

The script in question has this header

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "subastas.settings")
import django
django.setup()
```

I copyed everything exact as I have in my other computer

```
subastas/
|-- ah
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- api
|   |   |-- apiFunciones.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- __pycache__
|   |       |-- apiFunciones.cpython-35.pyc
|   |       `-- __init__.cpython-35.pyc
|   |-- apps.py
|   |-- busquedas
|   |   |-- busquedas.py
|   |   |-- datos.py
|   |   `-- __pycache__
|   |       |-- busquedas.cpython-35.pyc
|   |       `-- datos.cpython-35.pyc
|   |-- config.py
|   |-- correos
|   |   |-- funciones.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- __pycache__
|   |       |-- funciones.cpython-35.pyc
|   |       `-- __init__.cpython-35.pyc
|   |-- graficas
|   |   |-- GraficasFunciones.py
|   |   |-- GraficaTest.py
|   |   `-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- logs
|   |   `-- registro.txt
|   |-- migrations
|   |   |-- 0001_initial.py
|   |   |-- 0002_auto_20170125_1727.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- __pycache__
|   |       |-- 0001_initial.cpython-35.pyc
|   |       |-- 0002_auto_20170125_1727.cpython-35.pyc
|   |       `-- __init__.cpython-35.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- obtenerCotizaciones.py
|   |-- __pycache__
|   |   |-- admin.cpython-35.pyc
|   |   |-- config.cpython-35.pyc
|   |   |-- __init__.cpython-35.pyc
|   |   `-- models.cpython-35.pyc
|   |-- resultados
|   |   |-- graficas
|   |   |   |-- evolucionFrasco de Agilidad.svg
|   |   |   |-- evolucionFrasco de Fuerza.svg
|   |   |   |-- evolucionFrasco de Intelecto.svg
|   |   |   `-- evolucionRosaluz.svg
|   |   |-- Rozaluz.csv
|   |   `-- temporal.json
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- views.py
|   `-- zips
|       |-- testFactory.py
|       `-- zfactory.py
|-- db.sqlite3
|-- manage.py
`-- subastas
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- __pycache__
    |   |-- __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    |   |-- settings.cpython-35.pyc
    |   |-- urls.cpython-35.pyc
    |   `-- wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
    |-- settings.py
    |-- urls.py
    `-- wsgi.py
```

Comment: Please show the layout of your project, including the location of your script and the settings file.

Comment: I am tring to paste the 'tree output but it doesnt seem to work i'

Comment: I realize now that in the Win PC I have python 3.5 and in my debian 3.4, can that be the problem?

Comment: Possibly. Try to use the same python version when you create your virtual environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, It does the same errore

Comment: You really should take sometime to learn using a versioning tool such as git `https://git-scm.com/` and how to setup a Python project using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools and a proepr  `setup.py` file. Moving the project aroudn should be a non-issue.

Comment: I will follow your suggestion right now, but  meanwhile I still have the problem

Comment: Nice - I've added a workaround that should work on the asnwer bellow.

Comment: What's the name of the script that is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add your root folder to Python's PYTHONPATH environment variable  - that way, it will find out both `subastas` and `ah` as Python packages that can be found.

From the bash prompt, standing at your root "subastas" Path type:

```
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`:$PYTHONPATH
```

But really, that is just a workaround - what you really need there is to prper configure your project with a `setup.py` file that make use of setuptools - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools , and just use PIP to install it locally (with the `pip develop` command) that will also solve your problem of dependencies.

And moreover, if you are not, you really should make use of a version control system for your project.

Answer (score 1):

Is a sum of settings and issues: pip + virtualenv + virtualenvwrapper see [tips-using-pip-virtualenv-virtualenvwrapper](http://mrcoles.com/tips-using-pip-virtualenv-virtualenvwrapper/)